# select Class using other element's text with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery Select Code is working if I use var c as certain Text

```
var className = $('#element').text(); //return value is 'class-text';

$el = $('.' + className);// Not Working, selecting Element
```

but text from element is not working.

```
var className = 'class-text'; 

$el = $('.' + className);// Working, selecting Element
```

Thank for any opinion to select Class using other element's text with jQuery

Comment: I attached jsfillde Please check the URL http://jsfiddle.net/76wcd4pc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like your option text have special character like below when i alert it :

[image: special]

Use this below code to remove those character. Only filter the alphanumeric value.

```
className = $('#element option:selected').text().replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/4hn6df5o/) - *see first and second alert.*

Comment: Weird right, do you copy those dropdown markup from somewhere? Anyway glad to hear that, and you're welcome mate.

Comment: weird in my osx chrome Two alerts are same

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution~!

Answer (score 4):

Use **[`$.trim()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/)** to remove white space from the beginning and end of a string.

**Update :** Some character is present at the beginning of the string so you need to remove that, You can use `\W` to select non word character and replace it.

```
var className = $.trim($('#element').text()).replace(/\W+/g,'');     
$el = $('.' + className);
```

Comment: Thanks for fast Answer but the code is not working too;

Comment: @JidoPark : please add your html

Comment: @JidoPark  :  maybe the classname is in lowercase

Comment: @JidoPark : in that case use toLowerCase() , https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase

Comment: I attached jsfillde Please check the URL

Comment: @JidoPark : you were added an unrecognizable character in your code delete it, then it will work http://jsfiddle.net/76wcd4pc/7/

Answer (score 0):

In this situation you should check if className is what you believe it to be:

```
var className = $('#element').text(); //return value is 'class-text';
alert('[' + className +']');

$el = $('.' + className);
```

In your JS Fiddle, you've got a strange character at the first position in option d. `<option>?ClassD</option>`

Just remove that and the code works:

```
<option>ClassD</option>
```

Comment: I've edited my answer accordingly. The strange character in <option value="6" selected="selected">￼classD</option> is your problem.